# Loading A .docx with PHPWord

Tags: php, ms-word, docx, phpword

I am attempting to load a .docx file with PHPWord, set a value in it, and save the file. The issue is the saved file comes out as a blank word document, 7kb in size. The document I put in is large and has multiple pages. Obviously its not loading it right. My code is as follows:

```
$PHPWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('Resources/documents/test.docx');

$document->setValue('theDate', '2014-07-25');

$xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
$xmlWriter->save("php://output");
```

I have tried with multiple test.docx files of different sorts, but the output file is always blank.

Comment: Have you seen this sample (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/samples/Sample_07_TemplateCloneRow.php) and tried the method saveAs ?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this issue with what Progi1984 linked, calling $document->saveAs() and then reading the file to download it. Thank you :)